# STRIPE PAYMENT GATEWAY - Error : "Customer cus_xxxx does not have card with ID tok_visa

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

// client side code

```
const onToken = async (token) =>
 { 
console.log(token);
 const bookingDetails = {
 room,
 userid: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))._id,
 fromdate, 
todate,
totalAmount, totaldays: totalDays, 
token, };
try {
    setLoading(true);
    const result = await axios.post("/api/bookings/bookroom", bookingDetails);
    setLoading(false);
    Swal.fire(
        "Congratulations",
        "Your Room Booked Successfully",
        "success"
    ).then((result) => {
        window.location.href = "/home";
    });
} catch (error) {
    setError(error);
    Swal.fire("Opps", "Error:" + error, "error");
}
setLoading(false);
};

return ( 
< StripeCheckout 
amount = { totalAmount * 100 }
 currency = "USD" token = { onToken } 
stripeKey = "PUBLIC_KEY_STRIPE" > 
< button className = "btn btn-primary" > Pay Now < /button> 
< /StripeCheckout>
 )
```

// server side code

```
const express = require("express"); const moment = require("moment"); const stripe = require("stripe")("PIRVATE_KEY"); const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const router = express.Router();

const Booking = require("../models/booking"); const Room = require("../models/room");

router.post("/bookroom", async (req, res) => { 
const { room, userid, fromdate, todate, totalAmount, totaldays, token } = req.body;
try {
    //create customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: token.email,
        source: token.id,
    });

    // //charge payment
    const payment = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: totalAmount * 100,
        customer: customer.id,
        currency: "USD",
        receipt_email: token.email,
        source: "tok_visa",
    }, {
        idempotencyKey: uuidv4(),
    });

    //Payment Success
    if (payment) {
        try {
            const newBooking = new Booking({
                room: room.name,
                roomid: room._id,
                userid,
                fromdate: moment(fromdate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
                todate: moment(todate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
                totalamount: totalAmount,
                totaldays,
                transactionid: uuidv4(),
            });
            console.log(newBooking);
            const booking = await newBooking.save();

            const roomTmp = await Room.findOne({
                _id: room._id
            });
            roomTmp.currentbookings.push({
                bookingid: booking._id,
                fromdate: moment(fromdate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
                todate: moment(todate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
                userid: userid,
                status: booking.status,
            });

            await roomTmp.save();
            res.send("Payment Successful, Your Room is booked");
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: error
            });
        }
    }
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        message: error
    });
}
});

module.exports = router;
```

Actually whenever I make payment:

[image]

this 404 image comes after clicking on the paynow:

> **POST http://localhost:3000/api/bookings/bookroom 400 (Bad Request)**

And error:

> "Customer cus_xxxx does not have card with ID tok_visa

This error is found in the networks of booknow route when the API call is made from the client side to server side.

```
"message": {
        "type": "StripeInvalidRequestError",
        "raw": {
            "code": "resource_missing",
            "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
            "message": "Customer cus_OPAVG030uMFGi0 does not have card with ID tok_visa",
            "param": "card",
            "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_8synDPKjmUX6v9?t=1691386789",
            "type": "invalid_request_error",
```

Comment: you need to link card to the customer. https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/attach

Comment: can you tell the source code

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass

```js
source: "tok_visa",
```

when creating a Charge. That `source` parameters expects a value in format `src_xxxx` and should be created on [client-side](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/cards#create-source).

But before that, Charge is a legacy API and you should use PaymentIntent instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass customer **default_source** as source in charge create API. https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers

```
const payment = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: totalAmount * 100,
        customer: customer.id,
        currency: "USD",
        receipt_email: token.email,
        source: customer.default_source,
    }, {
        idempotencyKey: uuidv4(),
    });
```